# PostgreSQL combine LAG and LEAD to query n previous and following rows

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, linguistics

I have a PostgreSQL table, let's call it *tokens*, containing grammatical annotations per token in lines of text, basically like this:

```
idx | line | tno | token   | annotation      | lemma
----+------+-----+---------+-----------------+---------
  1 | I.01 | 1   | This    | DEM.PROX        | this
  2 | I.01 | 2   | is      | VB.COP.3SG.PRES | be
  3 | I.01 | 3   | an      | ART.INDEF       | a
  4 | I.01 | 4   | example | NN.INAN         | example
```

I want to make a query that allows me to search for grammatical contexts, in this case, a query that checks whether a certain annotation is present in a window of size *n* before and after the current row. From what I read up on this, PostgreSQL's Window Functions `LEAD` and `LAG` are suitable to achieve this. As a first shot, I wrote the following query based on documentation I could find about these functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT token, annotation, lemma,
        -- LAG(annotation) OVER prev_rows AS prev_anno, -- ?????
        LEAD(annotation) OVER next_rows AS next_anno
    FROM tokens
    WINDOW next_rows AS (
        ORDER BY line, tno ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING
    )
    ORDER BY line, tno ASC
) AS "window"
WHERE
    lemma LIKE '...'
    AND "window".next_anno LIKE '...'
;
```

However, this only searches the 2 following rows. My question is, how can I rephrase the query to make the window include both previous and following rows in the table? Apparently, I can't have 2 `WINDOW` statements or do something like

```
ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
AND ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quiet sure if I got your use case correctly: You want to check if one given annotation is in one of the 5 rows (2 preceding, current, 2 following). Correct?

---

1. It is possible to define a window like `BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING`
2. `LEAD` or `LAG` only give one value, in this case the one value after or before the current row - if a window supports it; no matter how many rows your window contains. But you want to check in any of these five rows.

One way to achieve this:

---

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c734672126822cd4238f32cfa40edb2e)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT token, annotation, lemma,
        unnest(array_agg(annotation) OVER w) as surrounded_annos      -- 2
    FROM tokens
    WINDOW w AS (                                                     -- 1
        ORDER BY line, tno ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING
    )
    ORDER BY line, tno ASC
) AS "window"
WHERE
    lemma LIKE '...'
    AND "window".surrounded_annos LIKE '...'
;
```

1. defining the window as explained above
2. 1. aggregate all annotations in these five rows (if possible) with `array_agg` which gives an array
   2. `unnest` expands this array into one row for every element since IMHO there is no way to search array elements with `LIKE`. This gives you this result (which can be filtered in the next step):

Result subquery:

```
token     annotation        lemma     surrounded_annos
This      DEM.PROX          this      DEM.PROX
This      DEM.PROX          this      VB.COP.3SG.PRES
This      DEM.PROX          this      ART.INDEF
is        VB.COP.3SG.PRES   be        DEM.PROX
is        VB.COP.3SG.PRES   be        VB.COP.3SG.PRES
is        VB.COP.3SG.PRES   be        ART.INDEF
is        VB.COP.3SG.PRES   be        NN.INAN
an        ART.INDEF         a         DEM.PROX
an        ART.INDEF         a         VB.COP.3SG.PRES
an        ART.INDEF         a         ART.INDEF
an        ART.INDEF         a         NN.INAN
example   NN.INAN           example   VB.COP.3SG.PRES
example   NN.INAN           example   ART.INDEF
example   NN.INAN           example   NN.
```

Comment: This seems to basically do what I want (thank you!), however, if the surrounded_annos filter condition is negative (NOT LIKE), is there a way to eliminate a token if the predicate of the filter condition is found in window? So: `WHERE lemma LIKE 'an' AND "window".surrounded_annos NOT LIKE '%VB.COP%'` should return an empty result because the row which contains 'an' *has* a neighbor for which `LIKE '%VB.COP%'` is true.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to compute the relative position of every token within the sentence, and perform a self-join of tokens<-->tokens (this will allow you to select *skip-grams* based on distance):

---

```
WITH www AS (   -- enumerate word posision with sentences
    SELECT line, tno    -- candidate key
        , row_number() OVER sentence AS rn
    FROM tokens
    WINDOW sentence AS ( ORDER BY line ASC, tno ASC)
        )
SELECT t0.line AS line
        , t0.token AS this
        , t1.tno AS tno
        , w1.rn - w0.rn AS rel  -- relative position
        , t1.token AS that
        , t1.annotation AS anno
FROM tokens t0
JOIN tokens t1 ON t1.line = t0.line     -- same sentence
JOIN www w0 ON t0.line = w0.line AND t0.tno= w0.tno -- PK1
JOIN www w1 ON t1.line = w1.line AND t1.tno= w1.tno -- PK2
WHERE 1=1
AND t0.lemma LIKE 'be'
    -- AND t1.annotation LIKE '.PROX' AND w1.rn - w0.rn  = -1
        ;

-- But, if you rno is consecutive(gapless) within lines,
-- you can omit the enumeration step, and do a plain self-join:

SELECT t0.line AS line
        , t0.token AS this
        , t1.tno AS tno
        , t1.tno - t0.tno AS rel        -- relative position
        , t1.token AS that
        , t1.annotation AS anno
FROM tokens t0
JOIN tokens t1 ON t1.line = t0.line     -- same sentence
WHERE 1=1
AND t0.lemma LIKE 'be'
    -- AND t1.annotation LIKE '.PROX' AND w1.rn - w0.rn  = -1
        ;
```